# What's an alternative idiom to "rob Peter to pay Paul?"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for an alternative to the phrase, but I can't seem to figure any out.

What's an alternative to "rob Peter to pay Paul?"

Comment: Are you asking strictly regarding theft? Or just an idiom that means one part (of the whole) antagonizing the other part (of the same whole) possibly without the other part knowing? Using the phrase in context would be more helpful.

Comment: [Credit card juggling](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2001/nov/10/jobsandmoney) is obviously highly context-specific. But we don't actually *know* OP's exact context. It could even be that [spoil the ship for a ha'porth of tar](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=767836) might be more appropriate. More context, please, Mr_Spock!

Comment: I don't think use of the phrase in a particular context is necessary here since the idiom is widely used and extremely straight-forward. In fact, I don't see how it can be misinterpreted. Essentially: "take from one resource to provide for another." It doesn't have to entail stealing per se.

Comment: It means to solve a problem temporarily by creating a new problem (in the example of Peter and Paul, paying off a loan by borrowing from someone else).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the *spoil the ship ...* maxim is more akin to [*for want of a nail ...*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail) where a minor expenditure earleir would forestall a greater expenditure later. *Peter and Paul* is just a shell game moving the same debt around.

Comment: In organized crime circles, an alternative phrase is, "We're gonna break your legs!"

Comment: In accounting terms, it's called juggling your liabilities. More specifically, it's trying to juggle five balls at the same time when your limit is three. Take the debtor who was being harassed by phone-calls from creditors. Completely fed up with their calls, he said to one particularly demanding creditor, "I decide which bill to pay by putting them all in a hat, and I blindly pick one. If you still want to be put into the hat, I suggest you stop calling me!"

Comment: @bib: Like I said, we don't have a full context. The *nail* maxim is usually used in contexts where a missing vital part causes major problems, but the *ha'porth of tar* (which specifically mentions a *small cost not expended*) could well be appropriate if you were saving a little money in one department's budget, causing far more money to be wasted in another. Robbing "Office Consumables" to pay for the Purchasing Department's need to get the order shipped and invoiced, so to speak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From googling I see, from China, "dismantle the West wall to repair the East wall".

Answer (score 8):

Trying to cover yourself with a short sheet.

Answer (score 4):

"Cutting off your nose to spite your face" is similar, but not exactly analogous.

Comment: "To cut of your nose to spite your face" often suggests malice, vindictiveness, or petulance by the actor. Robbing Peter to pay Paul does not have that connotation.  It means trying to shift benefits to cover bases in an inefficient and probably short-term manner.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **[shell game](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/shell%20game)**

> A fraud or deception perpetrated by shifting conspicuous things to hide something else.

The phrase is based on a street scam, also called [thimblerig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_game)

The term is often used for dishonest dealings in which the money/asset/payoff is constantly being shifted to avoid actual delivery of a payoff. Many *[ponzi schemes](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ponzi-scheme)* use this type of shuffling short-term payments

> a fraudulent investment operation that pays quick returns to initial contributors using money from subsequent contributors rather than profit

Answer (score 2):

Personal experience is all I can offer to this discussion. Most people have engaged in this practice when we use too little resources ( usually money),and juggle it so that enough debts are satisfied for the near term. If it's true that over 3/4 of the us public ***lives paycheck to paycheck***, then we Americans might be considered experts at this practice. Not a distinction that we should take pride in.  rk

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is "making [it] someone else's problem," or "passing the buck." In the case of the idiom you are making it Peter's problem (or passing the buck to Peter, if you prefer).

Comment: Actually, the phrase has the opposite meaning.  `Peter` and `Paul` here refer to the Christian apostles, generally thought of as a team moreso than as individuals.  So if you rob Peter to give to Paul, you haven't really accomplished anything, not even `passing the buck`.  The Peter/Paul team is neither better nor worse than before.  Another interpretation is that you're trying to do something righteous ("paying Paul") but you've committed a sin ("robbing Peter") to do it.  So regardless of Peter/Paul's relationship, in the end you're not doing anything positive for *yourself* either.

Comment: @dg99, I think that this is more of a subjective thing. When I suggested it, the proverbial buck was your debt to Paul, which you passed to peter by stealing from him.

Comment: @dg99 - *Peter* and *Paul* refer to cathedrals in England, and the expression comes from the fact that a body (I don't recall whose) entombed at St Peter's was disinterred and re-entombed at St Paul's, because the backers of St Paul's felt they "deserved it" more.

Answer (score 0):

Steal from the rich to give to the poor.